# running facebook-php-sdk-master example from local_host

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to develop an app using facebook php sdk, but i had problem running the example.php from localhost.

I see a blank page when i try this url in my browser:

`://localhost/facebook-php-sdk-master/examples/example.php`

My folder structure is

`/var/www/facebook-php-sdk-master/examples/example.php`

i have used
app domains: `localhost`
and site url: `http://localhost/facebook-php-sdk-master/`

but no success, but only a blank page. what should i do?

Comment: site url = http://localhost/facebook-php-sdk-master/examples/

Comment: site must be `http://localhost/facebook-php-sdk-master/examples/example.php` not `http://localhost/facebook-php-sdk-master/`

Comment: i tried site url as http://localhost/facebook-php-sdk-master/examples/example.php     and i also tried http://localhost/facebook-php-sdk-master/examples/   and i also tried http://localhost/facebook-php-sdk-master/  but still no success but a blank page

Comment: [Tue Jan 14 01:46:30 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.' in /var/www/facebook-php-sdk-master/src/base_facebook.php:19\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php(18): require_once()\n#1 /var/www/facebook-php-sdk-master/examples/example.php(18): require('/var/www/facebo...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/facebook-php-sdk-master/src/base_facebook.php on line 19

Comment: enable "CURL PHP extension" on LAMP

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: This IP can't make requests for that application. thrown in C:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-master\src\base_facebook.php on line 1332.      i think the error is in site url, it gives the same error with every site url that i update

Comment: PHP based SDK doesn't work on `localhost` try your app on public server